# If you had a list of common words from Middle and Modern English, how many words would have been replaced?

Tags: history, historical-change, middle-english

If you compiled a list of common Middle English words and their corresponding Modern English translations, how many entries would have been replaced by an etymologically distinct word in Modern English? It's difficult to Google, since I just get articles on the vocabulary changes from Old to Middle English, which is not what I want.

By 'common', I mean concepts you would expect people to have a word for in both eras, like *go*, *hand* or *red*, and by 'replace', whether the default word is a direct descendant of the Middle English word in both meaning and form or if it was replaced by another word, either native or loaned.

So, *tongue* would count as retained, since it existed with the same meaning and use in Middle English. While *dog* would be a replacement, since while *hound* exists today and *dog* existed then, *dog* is the default word now where *hound* was before.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Modern English spelling is designed for Middle English (it was standardized by printers before the Great Vowel Shift was complete), so written Middle English **looks** like written Modern English. But if you heard Middle English, you wouldn't understand  it, because it does not **sound** like Modern English; and that's why there's a difference.

Comment: Are you looking for *spelling* changes or *phonological* changes?

Comment: I'm looking for *lexical* changes. The replacement of one word by another.

Comment: Despite its non-etymological ending, _tongue_ is Germanic: Old Eng. _tunge_, Mod. Ger. _Zunge_.

Comment: @KarlG Oh, I think I misread my source. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start for a list of common words is a [Swadesh list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swadesh_list). They have questionable usefulness in some cases, but I believe it's a decent tool for comparing iterations of a language.

Wiktionary has a 207-word [Middle English (ME) Swadesh list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Middle_English_Swadesh_list), conveniently with the modern word listed. Of course, it's hard to count some words, because if they were replaced in the roughly 350-year span of ME, are we counting them as ME or not?

Some findings:

- The top 26 words (mostly pronouns) seem to be related. The 27th word is "big," which the list gives as in ME as "*large, larche, largh, grete, gret, greet*."
- Modern English (MdE) words that have changed: *big, wide, animal, bird, dog* (nice one), *to vomit, to split, to stab, to squeeze, to push, fog, road, dirty, dull, correct*
- MdE words given with primary translations that have different roots, but have secondary translations that line up: *man (male), forest, bark (tree), skin, belly,  guts, back, to know, to die, to kill, to dig, to walk, river, with*

All this together gives **15-29 (7-14%) replacements**, depending on how you count.

Note though, that I'm not a scholar of English, and could have made oversights or misjudgements in tallying. Happy to accept corrections or additions from people more versed in M/MdE than me. I also didn't click through the majority to make sure they are related, just going off sounds and what knowledge I do have about historical English.